# String in parentheses

Tags: crystal-reports

I recently have seen an expression in Crystal. It's a formula, when I edit it, its content is something like this:

```
("sNumber") + ":"
```

However, when I print this report, the code above will become: `Number:`

I think `("sNumber")` is something like a variable. But I cannot find where it is be declared. I searched a lot on web but I find nothing.

So my question is:

1. Where can I find it?
2. How can I edit its value?

Any help would be welcome!

**UPDATE:**

I tried some expression, and find out all string after "s" will be displayed on the report, and those before "s" will be removed.

Maybe it's just some string expression not in document. **If someone knows the specification, please add below.**

Comment: I don't think its a variable because if it is a variable then there is no need that it should be declared between `""`

Comment: @Siva It's not a declaration. Another example: <code>("sTitle")</code> will be expanded as "Report Title". Anyway "string" in () will not be outputted directly.

Comment: Maybe your field is not wide enough to print the entire string "sNumber", so it is truncated to "Number"?

Comment: @PaulWilliams I tried some expression, and find out all string after "s" will be displayed on the report, and those before "s" will be removed. Maybe it's just some string expression.

Comment: this sounds like it may be an in-house formula expression and not part of the vanilla CR.  Could CR be attached to an BusinessObjects Enterprise server, or any of the SAP Connection types?  if it was a formula it would look like {@test} and if this was a variable it would be using the formula.  is ("sNumber") all that located in the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further test, I have to say it is not a variable. It's just that everything after the letter "s" will be printed.

But I can see the whole string "sNumber" in the preview view.

My conclusion is if I want to change it, just modify the string after "s".

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Formula `"(""sNumber"") :"` if you just need to create it as string

Comment: This is not what I want.